# Prevent Delta table merge to create a lot of small files?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake

I am merging an update dataframe into a big Delta table. When doing so I noticed that the amount of parquet files increases drastically. I know that afterwards I can perform a vacuum command on that table with a retention period of 0 hours. However, I think this is pretty inefficient. Is there a way to turn off the delta versioning? I thought of converting that delta table into a parquet table but then I'm not able to perform a merge anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the only suggestions I found to reduce this effect are listed here:

> https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-update.html#language-python